# Conjectured formula for the standard Clausen function

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, riemann-zeta, conjectures

I often guess generalizations based on subtle patterns. I found the following formula in such a way and I wonder how it can be proven.

Let $n$ be a non-negative integer. Then

\begin{align}
\text{Cl}_{n}(x)&=(-1)^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}x^{n-1}\left(\frac{H_{n-1}-\ln x}{\Gamma(n)}+\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^k\frac{\zeta(2k+1)}{x^{2k}\Gamma(n-2k)}+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\zeta(2k)\Gamma(2k)}{\Gamma(n+2k)}\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}\right)^{2k}\right)
\\&=(-1)^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}\left(\psi^{(-n)}(x)-\psi^{(-n)}(x+1)+\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^k\frac{x^{n-2k-1}\zeta(2k+1)}{\Gamma(n-2k)}+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n+2k-1}\zeta(2k)\Gamma(2k)}{(2\pi)^{2k}\Gamma(n+2k)}\right)
\end{align}

where $\text{Cl}_{n}(x)$ is one of the standard [Clausen functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function) defined by

$$
\text{Cl}_{n}(x)=
\begin{cases}
 \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(kx)}{k^n}& n\space\text{even}\\\\
 \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(kx)}{k^n}& n\space\text{odd}
\end{cases}
$$

**Edit:** Upon further investigation, the proof can likely be derived from equations 2.7 and 2.8 of [this paper](http://files.ele-math.com/articles/mia-16-76.pdf).